# how to use videojs resolution switcher in reactjs with example

Tags: reactjs, video.js, screen-resolution

How to use videojs resolution switcher in reactjs

**Component 1**
~

```
const videoJsOptions = {
    autoplay: false,
    controls: true,
    mute:true,
    aspectRatio: "16:9",
    playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]
};
let videoSourse = [{
        src: 'videos/intros/Intro480_30_Condensed.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '480'
    }, {
        src: 'videos/intros/Intro720_30_Condensed.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        label: '720'
}]; 
<VideoJsPlayer
    {...videoJsOptions}
    onPlayerPlay={this.onPlayerPlay}
    onPlayerEnd={this.onPlayerEnd}
    sources={videoSource}
/>
```

~

**component 2**

```
<video id="video" ref={node => (this.videoNode = node)} className="video-js vjs-default-skin videoPlayer" />
```

i want to use multiple resolution within same video and can swith between all

Comment: I think you can use this https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher

Comment: i have tried but getting error **videoJsResolutionSwitcher** not exit

Comment: @NiyasNazar if you know can you help me

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io) to reproduce what you tried?

Comment: @NiyasNazar can i provide skype session right now or give me some time for codesandbox